# How do you sort an array of objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an object as follows:

```
[{:id=>2, :fname=>"Ron", :lname=>"XXXXX", :photo=>"XXX"}, {:id=>3, :fname=>"Dain", :lname=>"XXXX", :photo=>"XXXXXXX"}, {:id=>1, :fname=>"Bob", :lname=>"XXXXXX", :photo=>"XXXX"}]
```

I want to sort this by fname, alphabetically case insensitive so it would result in

id: 1,3,2

How can I sort this? I'm trying:

```
@people.sort! { |x,y| y[:fname] <=> x[:fname] }
```

But that has no effect.

Comment: That is not a JSON object. That is a Ruby array of hashes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by).

```
@people.sort_by! { |x| x[:fname].downcase }
```

(the downcase is for the case insensitivity)

For completeness, the issues with the provided code are:

- the arguments are in the wrong order
- downcase is not being called

The following code works using the sort method.

```
@people.sort! { |x,y| x[:fname].downcase <=> y[:fname].downcase }
```

As proof that both of these methods do the same thing:

```
@people.sort_by {|x| x[:fname].downcase} == @people.sort { |x,y| x[:fname].downcase <=> y[:fname].downcase }
```

Returns **true**.